# Proof for existence of Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, brownian-motion

Is there any easy way to prove that Brownian Motion exists? If there is not, is there a source where I could look up a complete proof?

Comment: In what sense do you mean that Brownian motion "exists"?

Comment: I think the proof is that in $L^2$, there is only one unique sequence of random variables that is continuous but nowhere differentiable. Since these are the properties one derives for BM, one can show the process exists in $L^2$. But I am not entirely sure about this. I've seen this existence proof before, and part of my motivation is to understand why it's necessary in the first place.